# Newbie Javascript function returning undefined, rock paper scissors game

Tags: javascript

As a newbie, following the code academy course, I've come across a problem building a rock paper scissors game.

I've created 2 functions which contain the whole program, the program runs fine when the 2 choices are different but it returns undefined when the choices are the same and I can't understand why.

I can see that when the choices are tied, new choices keep being assigned until they are different and then the compare function is called on these different choices, which should return a winning result.

Just to add, I'd like to fix the code as it is, not rewrite the entire thing, I've completed this exercise on codeacademy but I'm just trying to do it in a different way as 2 self contained functions.

Thanks

```
var makeChoices = function() {
userChoice = "";
computerChoice = "";

userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} 

console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice + " " + "User: " + userChoice);
};

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        makeChoices();
        compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins";
        }
        else {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
    else {
        return "invalid choice by user";
    }
};

makeChoices();
compare (userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Comment: I've learned from someone that the reason is as Damon said, the missing return statement but I'm not quite getting why that is the problem because the compare function does return an answer already.

Can anyone help explain this in a way I can understand pls?  Thanks  :)

Comment: See the response under my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the result of the recursive call. Try changing

```
...
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
...
```

to

```
...
return compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
...
```

Comment: Ah thanks Damon...but why? when the choices are different, shouldn't the code fall into one of the other if statements which return a result already?

Comment: @jobe think of it this way - When you are making a recursive call, a new function is invoked. That function returns a value. Now we're back into the parent function, and we have that value floating in space but what do we want to do with it? We still have to return it from the parent function as well. Otherwise, the parent function still has no explicit return value and will return undefined. TL;DR Just because the child returns a value to the parent, does not mean the parent will automatically return that value.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful way to help me understand  :)

Answer (score 0):

I made such a game before:

```
var prsStatements = {
  paperBeatsRock: 'Paper Beats Rock',
  rockBeatsScissors: 'Rock Beats Scissors',
  scissorsBeatsPaper: 'Scissors Beats Paper',
  seperator: ' - ',
  player1: 'Player One',
  player2: 'Player Two',
  wins: ' Wins!',
  tie: "It's a Tie!",
  tally: 'Final Tally: '
}
function PaperRockScissors(player1, player2){
  var p = /^paper$/i, r = /^rock$/i, s = /^scissors$/i, prss = prsStatements, sep = prss.seperator, win = prss.wins;
  var pbr = prss.paperBeatsRock+sep, rbs = prss.rockBeatsScissors+sep, sbp = prss.scissorsBeatsPaper+sep;
  var plr1 = player1 ? player1 : prss.player1;
  var plr2 = player2 ? player2 : prss.player2;
  var p1w = plr1+win, p2w = plr2+win;
  this.p1 = 0; this.p2 = 0;
  this.rand = function(){
    switch(Math.floor(Math.random()*3)){
      case 0:
        return 'rock';
      case 1:
        return 'paper';
      case 2:
        return 'scissors';
    }
  }
  this.play = function(in1, in2){
    var i2 = in2 || this.rand();
    if(in1.match(p) && i2.match(r)){
      ++this.p1;
      return pbr+p1w;
    }
    else if(i2.match(p) && in1.match(r)){
      ++this.p2;
      return pbr+p2w;
    }
    else if(in1.match(r) && i2.match(s)){
      ++this.p1;
      return rbs+p1w;
    }
    else if(i2.match(r) && in1.match(s)){
      ++this.p2;
      return rbs+p2w;
    }
    else if(in1.match(s) && i2.match(p)){
      ++this.p1;
      return sbp+p1w;
    }
    else if(i2.match(s) && in1.match(p)){
      ++this.p2;
      return sbp+p2w;
    }
    else if(in1.match(i2r)){
      return prss.tie;
    }
    else{
      return this;
    }
  }
  this.tally = function(){
    var pt = prss.tally;
    if(this.p1 > this.p2){
      return pt+p1w;
    }
    else if(this.p2 > this.p1){
      return pt+p2w;
    }
    else{
      return pt+prss.tie;
    }
  }
}
var pr = new PaperRockScissors('Joe', 'Bob');
console.log(pr.play('paper', 'rock'));
console.log(pr.play('rock', 'Paper'));
console.log(pr.play('scissors', 'paper'));
console.log(pr.play('rock', 'Paper'));
console.log(pr.play('paper', 'rock'));
console.log(pr.play('Paper', 'Scissors'));
console.log(pr.play('Paper', 'paper'));
console.log(pr.play('paper', 'Rock'));
console.log(pr.tally());
```

If you want to make this web-functional you would simply pass user input values, like:

```
pr.play(someElement.value, anotherElement.value);
```

Of course, you would want to use an Event and pass the correct values of either 'paper', 'rock', or 'scissors'.

Computer play might look like:

```
var pc = new PaperRockScissors('Joe', 'Comupter');
console.log(pc.play('paper'));
console.log(pc.play('rock'));
console.log(pc.play('scissors'));
console.log(pc.play('rock'));
console.log(pc.play('paper'));
console.log(pc.play('Paper'));
console.log(pc.play('Paper'));
console.log(pc.play('paper'));
console.log(pc.tally());
```

Comment: Sorry my Javascript knowledge isn't so advanced and your code wasn't easy for me to understand.

Comment: That's cool. You can look at this in the future and realized how much you've learned since you originally asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

When it is equal, you have "compare(userChoice, computerChoice);".  The variables userChoice and computerChoice were defined in the makeChoices() function.  They won't be available in compare() function.  You can make them  as global variables or consider moving you the compare() function calls to the bottom of makeChoices().

Comment: They are global variables.

Answer (score 0):

We all start the same way this impressive language!, do not worry about being a novice, you will soon be a teacher if you do not surrender!,here is the complete code for this exercise below:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
var compare = function(computerChoice, userChoice) {
if (computerChoice===userChoice) {
     return("The result is a tie!");
 }
if (userChoice === "rock"){
   if (computerChoice === "paper") {
return("paper wins");
}
else if (computerChoice === "scissors") {
    return("rock wins");
 }
}
if (userChoice === "scissors") {
     if (computerChoice==="paper") {
       return("scissors wins");
 }
 else if (computerChoice === "rock") {
    return("rock wins");
      }
   }
if (userChoice === "rock") {
if (computerChoice==="scissors") {
    return "rock wins";
}
else if (computerChoice=== "paper") {
    return "paper wins";
}
}
if (userChoice === "paper") {
if (computerChoice ==="scissors") {
    return "scissors wins";
}
else if (computerChoice==="rock") {
    return "paper wins";
    }
   }
 };
compare();
```

Comment: Thanks Cesar, I'd got to this point before, I should clarify my original comment, I've tried to develop the code to make both the choice part and the compare part functions. I'm looking to figure out why it's not working in the new way that I've tried to structure it.